# query MongoDB when two fields match two values at the same time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that keeps applications' allowed actions like this:

```
const appAccess = [
  {
    appId: 111,
    scope: 'get-user',
  },
  {
    appId: 111,
    scope: 'update-user',
  },
  {
    appId: 111,
    scope: 'delete-user',
  },
  {
    appId: 222,
    scope: 'get-user',
  },
  {
    appId: 222,
    scope: 'update-user',
  },
  {
    appId: 333,
    scope: 'delete-user',
  },
];
```

also I have a collection that keeps logs of application actions on users, this is an example in that collection:

```
const appActions = [
  {
    _id: 123,
    appId: 111,
    scope: 'get-user',
    user: 10,
  },
  {
    _id: 456,
    appId: 111,
    scope: 'update-user',
    user: 20,
  },
  {
    _id: 567,
    appId: 111,
    scope: 'delete-user',
    user: 30,
  },
  {
    _id: 678,
    appId: 222,
    scope: 'update-user',
    user: 50,
  },
  {
    _id: 789,
    appId: 222,
    scope: 'get-user',
    user: 60,
  },
  {
    _id: 890,
    appId: 333,
    scope: 'delete-user',
    user: 70,
  },
];
```

now imagine I want to select all `update-user` actions done by application `111` and all `get-user` actions done by application `222`, how can I do that?

Comment: You can try an aggregation `$lookup` query for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [conditional $lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection) syntax, like so:

```
db.actions.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      scope: "delete-user"//get actions
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "performed_actions",
      "let": {
        appId: "$appId",
        scope: "$scope"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$appId",
                    "$appId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$scope",
                    "$scope"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "matchedActions"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UJszmRsIQTB)

Comment: what happens if each app can have many scopes and many actions and we want to get all actions that some apps have in multiple scopes?

Comment: can you edit your question to include all the details you want?

Comment: I updated my question. I appreciate your assistance.